# Azure Redis connection failure when using SSL

Tags: azure, redis

I am using Spring Session with Redis using Azure Redis.

Things are working fine with the non-SSL port 6379.  However with the SSL port 6380, I get this error:

```
ERROR (org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer:651) || - Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms
```

That’s it.  No further information.

Here is my Redis configuration:

```
<bean id="redisPassword" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisPassword">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${spring.redis.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="redisStandaloneConfiguration" 
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration">
    <property name="hostName" value="${spring.redis.host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${spring.redis.port}"/>
    <property name="password" ref="redisPassword"/>
</bean>

<util:constant id="configureRedisAction"
               static-field="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP"/>

<bean id="lettuceClientConfiguration"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.DefaultLettuceClientConfiguration" 
      factory-method="defaultConfiguration">
</bean>
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration" 
      p:configureRedisAction-ref="configureRedisAction"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="redisStandaloneConfiguration"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="lettuceClientConfiguration"/>
</bean>
```

What is causing the connection failure?

Comment: maybe it can be the TLS version. try to change it in your azure portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#access-ports

Comment: So I should not use Lettuce?  What is a good alternative?

Comment: oh my bad ... didn't notice you're using lettuce. Have you start the tls? https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/SSL-Connections#starttls

Comment: Microsoft recommendation is jedis for SSL scenarios: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-java-get-started

Comment: Found this sample using Lettuce and port 6380: https://dev.to/azure/configuring-azure-redis-cache-to-boost-spring-boot-performance-7-7-52dl

Answer (score 0):

```
<util:constant id="configureRedisAction"
               static-field="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"
      p:configureRedisAction-ref="configureRedisAction"/>

<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <property name="maxTotal" value="200" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="50" />
    <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="30000" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${spring.redis.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${spring.redis.port}" />
    <property name="poolConfig" ref="jedisPoolConfig" />
    <property name="usePool" value="true" />
    <property name="useSsl" value="${spring.redis.ssl}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${spring.redis.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: It looks like the JedisConnectionFactory is deprecating some of those fields. Did you remove your RedisStandaloneConfiguration bean entirely?